# Is it possible to enter password once for 2 encrypted partitions at start-up?

Tags: 14.04, login, password, encryption

I have my ubuntu 14.04 installation set up with my / and swap partitions encrypted. They both have the same password. My /home is on a separate HDD. My user login password is different to that of the encrypted partitions. presently at start-up I have to enter my password for the / partition then the password for swap partition which then bring to the login screen.

Is there a workaround in that I can enter my password for the two encrypted partitions just once at start-up rather then having to enter it twice as I have to do now?